# Can not display html content into Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dialog

I have some html content to display in jquery dialog onclick. here is the sample code

html code (inside php) :

```
<div id = '".$id."' style='display:none' >".$toperrors." </div> 
<td align='center' onclick='toperrors($id);' > <img src='images/minimize.jpg' width=30     
height=20 ></img> </td>
```

Jquery :

```
function toperrors(str){
$("#dialog").html("");
 $("#dialog").html($("div#"+str).html());
   $("#dialog").dialog({
   title: "Top errors",
    modal: true,
    width: "800px",
     height: 400,
  buttons: 
 {"OK":function() {
 $(this).dialog("close");
  }
 }
 });
  }
```

if $toperrors contains  a string , the code working perfectly, without any issues.

But If I assign html content to $toperrors variable. then the html content printing on the web
  page itself.  perhaps its not hiding with style='display:none' in div. 
  any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You should never give a html id anything else then a pure string. Otherwise you will run into problems sooner or later..

Comment: Can you give an example of the html output that causes this behavior?

Comment: The HTML content is not properly a html content, because of copy pasting. I am using some html purifier. But the format is printing ok  on web page. because of my company NDA , I can not disaply the  output, sorry.

Comment: Well I guess that in that case the output breaks the html structure and therefore the css can't target your div correctly anymore and as a result the content is displayed and not hidden.

Comment: yes, what you said is sounds convincing to  me. Any idea how to over come this ?

Comment: It would be best if you assure that the html output is valid in the context of where it gets put in your existing html. It is really hard to give any recommendations without having an code example of the output.. ;)

Comment: Thanks  Sebsemillia , after I used http://htmlpurifier.org/ , the content is in proper html format and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags() or htmlentities()

```
<div id = '".strip_tags($id)."' style='display:none' >".$toperrors." </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. But it didn't help. sorry $toperrors  is the variable contains the html content, not $id.  It seems when $toperrors has html content it prints on the browser.